# What is the benefit of not returning anything for commands in the CQS pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

It's clear to me that performing some kind of modification to the underlying data when I do a "query" in a class would be misleading, like making `getMyValue()` do some kind of side effect. That would be difficult to reason about. But if I do some kind of update like `updateModel`, I don't see the problem with having it return a query, such as returning the correct state of an entity. I would assume that an error in the update would cause an exception to be thrown. Not returning any values just makes extra work to do a query.

What regrets would I have if I return values with commands in CQS?

Answer (score 0):

In general, how can the command know the future query? Isn't the goal of this pattern to separate them? When your command is designed to know the future query and able to create a corresponding query object, isn't it the same like having the command executing the query directly and just return the result, because concerns are already mixed?

The Pattern is meant to separate the different **concerns** of a command and a query. Means simply don't mix them.
Another rule is not to use exception handling to control the flow of the application. Exceptions also are making the application slow. The goal is to avoid *exception*s. Exception means exceptional by definition. Your command should rather return some error object or a boolean value. –
You are fine to return anything but result objects that can produce side effects, because this is an indicator, that concerns are mixed. The main idea of a command or action is fire and forget (same for events).